# Logrotate maually on FreeBSD 8

Tags: freebsd, logs, logrotate

I am able to rotate any log file manually via logroatate like this:

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/my-hourly-file
```

I want to know how to perform the same action on FreeBSD 8?

My investigation shows that `newsyslog` can be used for this purpose. If so how can I download and install `newsyslog`?

Update: I think `newsyslog` has been installed and modifying the `/etc/newsyslog.conf` file will be enough for automatic installation. But how can I trigger it manually?

Update2: when I search all newsyslog words starting from /, I only found /etc/rc.d/newsyslog script. Inside the script I realized that newsyslog command is defined under /usr/sbin/newsyslog. But there is not newsyslog file under /usr/sbin/newsyslog.

I am stuck that how I can install newsyslog package into FreBSD 8

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you're new to FreeBSD, and coming from a Linux background.

Let's clear a few things up --

First, `newsyslog` isn't a package -- it's a program that *comes with the base FreeBSD operating system*. You shouldn't have to install it, and it should always be there.
If `/usr/sbin/newsyslog` is missing from your system someone has deleted it (for reasons I can't fathom) -- Find the previous sysadmin and find out what they did, and why.
(You may optionally want to beat them with a stick for removing core OS utilities.)

If you need to get `newsyslog` back in a hurry you can rebuild it from source, or copy it from another 8.x system. If you're in less of a hurry you can [rebuild and install `world`](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/makeworld.html) which will also correct a number of other problems you may have on an inherited system (You should first make sure that this won't muck up any other measures you have in place for patching servers, and observe all the red boxes warning you to make backups).

---

Once you have `newsyslog` back you can force it to rotate log files one of two ways:

- `newsyslog -F`  will force ALL log files in `newsyslog.conf` to be rotated immediately.
- `newsyslog -R <files>` will force the specified files to be rotated immediately.

Further information can be found in [the `newsyslog` man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=newsyslog&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.3-stable&arch=default&format=html)

Comment: You are right I am new to FreeBSD, but I am sure that `/usr/sbin/newsyslog`
is missing and nobody has removed it. 
The installation of FreeBSD is alittle bit different  than usual. I am using Pfsense which is installed with FreeBSD, it comes with FreeBSD. It may effect something else that causes newsyslog installation?

Thanks.

Comment: Ahhh, `pfSense` is not FreeBSD (based on, certainly, but not the same).  I've no idea what they're using for log rotation, but that said you can just grab a copy of newsyslog from a FreeBSD 8 box (install one in a VirtualBox VM if necessary). You may optionally want to beat the pfSense people with a stick and admonish them not to remove core OS utilities (or ask them where they moved it to) :)

Comment: It's `newsyslog -R <tag> <files>` on my FreeBSD 10, where `<tag>` is just any short id string you want (it shows up in the log file to identify who rotated it).

Answer (score 0):

You can also install logrotate with pkg or ports collection, then configure /usr/local/etc/logrotate.conf. So you don't have to learn newsyslog.